# UI Automation new parent window got added in the apllication

Tags: c#, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I have automated an application using COded UI Framework and i have UIMaps organized in a modular fashion. Now my application is being contained with in another application i.e there is another 1 or two parent windows that got added to my existing application. How can i modiy the automation to work with this new structure without re -recording the UI Maps ?.

Answer (score 1):

If it's literally just an additional parent object/element/window or two above the others that are the same, then you can create a class for the new parent(s) and have the original extend that instead of WinWindow.

So if you originally have this:

```
public class OriginalWindowView : WinWindow
{
    public OriginalWindowView()
    {
        this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.???] = "something";
    }

    //child properties of this window here...
}
```

... you would simply create a new class for the new parent with the correct search properties:

```
public class NewWindowView : WinWindow
{
    public NewWindowView()
    {
        this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.???] = "somethingelse";
    }
}
```

... and then extend it thus from your original:

```
public class OriginalWindowView : NewWindowView
```